# Parse Nested JSON Dictionary Ansible

Tags: json, parsing, networking, ansible

I'm  trying to get the names of interfaces that meet a certain criteria within a given JSON in Ansible, using jmesquery.

The thing is that the items in the list are named, it's not a list containing all values per item in it, and can't figure how to filter it.

**With a condition that is vlan == "1"** this JSON should give as **output** something like **['GigabitEthernet0/0', 'GigabitEthernet0/1']**

After using dict2items (as @mdaniel suggested) I managed to apply the filter with conditions, but I'm struggling to retrieve the interface names which are now in *key*:

```
    - name: PRINT
      debug:
       msg: "{{ jsondata.interfaces | dict2items | json_query( query ) }}"
      vars:
       query: >-
        [][value][?vlan=='1']
```

JSON

```
        interfaces: {
               "GigabitEthernet0/0": {
                    "duplex_code": "auto",
                    "port_speed": "a-100",
                    "status": "connected",
                    "type": "10/100/1000BaseTX",
                    "vlan": "1"
              },
               "GigabitEthernet0/1": {
                    "duplex_code": "auto",
                    "port_speed": "a-100",
                    "status": "connected",
                    "type": "10/100/1000BaseTX",
                    "vlan": "1"
              } 
    }
```

JSON after applying jsondata.interfaces | dict2items

```
        [
           {
               "key": GigabitEthernet0/0",
               "value": {
                    "duplex_code": "auto",
                    "port_speed": "a-100",
                    "status": "connected",
                    "type": "10/100/1000BaseTX",
                    "vlan": "1"
                }
            },
            {
               "key": GigabitEthernet0/1",
               "value": {
                    "duplex_code": "auto",
                    "port_speed": "a-100",
                    "status": "connected",
                    "type": "10/100/1000BaseTX",
                    "vlan": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi sTz welcome to SO. Does that mean the [`|dict2items` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) does not work for you?

Comment: It is not a list. It is a dictionary. And the dictionary is not valid because the keys are not unique. [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Comment: @VladimirBotka sorry for that, I have modified the JSON, the problem is in fact it being a dictionary and not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few solutions:

```
- name: set_fact 
  set_fact:
    result: "{{ result | d([]) + [item.key] }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', jsondata.interfaces) }}"
  when: "'1' == item.value.vlan"
```

or using jinja2 loop:

```
- name: build
  set_fact:
    result: "{{ _request.strip(',').split(',') }}"
  vars:
    _query: "1"
    _request: >-
      {%- for k in jsondata.interfaces -%}
      {%-   if jsondata.interfaces[k].vlan == _query -%}
      {{ k }},
      {%-   endif  -%}
      {%- endfor  -%}
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  result:
  - GigabitEthernet0/0
  - GigabitEthernet0/1
```

Comment: That works for getting the keys, but not for applying a condition where a given parameter meets a criteria, in my case vlan == "1"

Answer (score 0):

For example, the task below does the job of listing the keys for *vlan=='1'*

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ interfaces|dict2items|
                 selectattr('value.vlan', 'eq', '1')|
                 map(attribute='key')|list }}"
```